# how to find maximum value without differentiating

Tags: maxima-minima

let x be positive real number, find max possible value of the expression
$$y = \frac{x^2 + 2 - \sqrt{x^4 + 4}}{x}$$

it can be found by differentiating, but is there no other way of finding it, like using AM $\geq$ GM.
or any other method.

i tried
$$y = x + \frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{4}{x^2}}$$
but it gives nothing

Comment: In what you tried you assumed $\;x>0\;$ , as you put the $\;x\;$ in the denominator inside the square root. Is this so?

Comment: yes,i did that, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: The function has no maximal value. This follows from the fact that it behaves "almost" as a straight line with slope 1 . Yet if you assume $\;x>0\;$ , as apparently you did, it does have a maximal value

Comment: @DonAntonio x is a positive number as mentioned i the question. Btw how did you assumed the function to be almost straight line.

Comment: You can graph the function, or else you can that its limit wne $\;x\to0\;$ is zero, and the limit of $\;f(x)-x\;$, with $\;f\;$ your function, is a constant number (in fact, $\;-1/2\;$ , I believe...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y(x) = x + \frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{4}{x^2}} = x + \frac{2}{x} -\sqrt{(x + \frac{2}{x})^2-4}$$
$$t=x+\frac{2}{x}$$
$$y(t)=t-\sqrt{t^2-4} =\frac{4}{t+\sqrt{t^2-4}}$$
which is clearly monotonicly decreasing.
so we need to find the minimal value of $x+\frac{2}{x}$
by AM-GM:
$$\frac{x+\frac{2}{x}}{2}\geq \sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track!

To begin with, suppose that $x > 0$. Then we can rearrange the proposed expression as
\begin{align*}
f(x) = x + \frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{x^{2} + \frac{4}{x^{2}}} = x + \frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{2}{x}\right)^{2} - 4}
\end{align*}

If we make the substitution $u = x + \dfrac{2}{x}$, one gets:
\begin{align*}
f(u) = u - \sqrt{u^{2} - 4}
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the derivative method. Analogous approach applies to the case where $x < 0$.

Can you take it from here?